# After CentOS 7.4 upgrade samba panic

Tags: centos, samba, centos7, upgrade, samba4

Hi we're running a Samba server 4.6.2 with Microsoft Active Directory integration. After upgrading CentOS 7.3 to version 7.4 our Samba server started throwing errors. Some users are unable to copy files from their desktop to the server.

Samba is crashing with core dumps and, after a restart, everything worked fine for half an hour and then Samba started logging errors again. Even after rebooting the server, Samba starts throwing errors. I've read the how-to section, but this provides only basic troubleshooting steps, nothing regarding an error quite as severe as this.

We're using CentOS 7.4 with the newest kernel version 3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.x86_64. Our fileserver has 16GB ram and 4 cpu cores. I would be happy about any help.

Here is my log file (/var/log/messages):

```
Sep 21 17:49:31 fs03 smbd[2160]: [2017/09/21 17:49:31.362559,  0] ../source3/lib/sysquotas.c:461(sys_get_quota)
Sep 21 17:49:31 fs03 smbd[2160]:  sys_path_to_bdev() failed for path [.]!
Sep 21 17:49:31 fs03 smbd[2160]: [2017/09/21 17:49:31.362980,  0] ../source3/lib/sysquotas.c:461(sys_get_quota)
Sep 21 17:49:31 fs03 smbd[2160]:  sys_path_to_bdev() failed for path [.]!
Sep 21 17:49:31 fs03 smbd[2160]: [2017/09/21 17:49:31.363008,  0] ../source3/lib/sysquotas.c:461(sys_get_quota)
Sep 21 17:49:31 fs03 smbd[2160]:  sys_path_to_bdev() failed for path [.]!
Sep 21 17:49:31 fs03 smbd[2160]: [2017/09/21 17:49:31.363034,  0] ../source3/lib/sysquotas.c:461(sys_get_quota)
Sep 21 17:49:31 fs03 smbd[2160]:  sys_path_to_bdev() failed for path [.]!
Sep 21 17:49:31 fs03 smbd[2160]: [2017/09/21 17:49:31.388115,  0] ../source3/lib/sysquotas.c:461(sys_get_quota)
Sep 21 17:49:31 fs03 smbd[2160]:  sys_path_to_bdev() failed for path [.]!
Sep 21 17:49:31 fs03 smbd[2160]: [2017/09/21 17:49:31.388174,  0] ../source3/lib/sysquotas.c:461(sys_get_quota)
Sep 21 17:49:31 fs03 smbd[2160]:  sys_path_to_bdev() failed for path [.]!
Sep 21 17:49:31 fs03 smbd[2160]: [2017/09/21 17:49:31.388212,  0] ../source3/lib/sysquotas.c:461(sys_get_quota)
Sep 21 17:49:31 fs03 smbd[2160]:  sys_path_to_bdev() failed for path [.]!
Sep 21 17:49:31 fs03 smbd[2160]: [2017/09/21 17:49:31.388238,  0] ../source3/lib/sysquotas.c:461(sys_get_quota)
Sep 21 17:49:31 fs03 smbd[2160]:  sys_path_to_bdev() failed for path [.]!
Sep 21 19:34:38 fs03 smbd[4287]: [2017/09/21 19:34:38.472673,  0] ../source3/lib/popt_common.c:67(popt_s3_talloc_log_fn)
Sep 21 19:34:38 fs03 smbd[4287]:  smb2_write failed: fnum 3657905683, file IT/tmp-files/10G (7), length=65536 offset=0 nwritten=-1: NT_STATUS_NETWORK_BUSY#012Bad talloc magic value - wrong talloc version used/mixed
Sep 21 19:34:38 fs03 smbd[4287]:  smb2_write failed: fnum 3657905683, file IT/tmp-files/10G (7), length=65536 offset=0 nwritten=-1: NT_STATUS_NETWORK_BUSY
Sep 21 19:34:38 fs03 smbd[4287]: [2017/09/21 19:34:38.473097,  0] ../source3/lib/util.c:791(smb_panic_s3)
Sep 21 19:34:38 fs03 smbd[4287]:  PANIC (pid 4287): Bad talloc magic value - wrong talloc version used/mixed
Sep 21 19:34:38 fs03 smbd[4287]: [2017/09/21 19:34:38.623999,  0] ../source3/lib/util.c:902(log_stack_trace)
Sep 21 19:34:38 fs03 smbd[4287]:  BACKTRACE: 8 stack frames:
Sep 21 19:34:38 fs03 smbd[4287]:   #0 /lib64/libsmbconf.so.0(log_stack_trace+0x1a) [0x7fbb77e336ba]
Sep 21 19:34:38 fs03 smbd[4287]:   #1 /lib64/libsmbconf.so.0(smb_panic_s3+0x20) [0x7fbb77e33790]
Sep 21 19:34:38 fs03 smbd[4287]:   #2 /lib64/libsamba-util.so.0(smb_panic+0x2f) [0x7fbb79f0e95f]
Sep 21 19:34:38 fs03 smbd[4287]:   #3 /lib64/libtalloc.so.2(_talloc_get_type_abort+0x102) [0x7fbb76c6b702]
Sep 21 19:34:38 fs03 smbd[4287]:   #4 /usr/lib64/samba/libmessages-dgm-samba4.so(+0x3c67) [0x7fbb75857c67]
Sep 21 19:34:38 fs03 smbd[4287]:   #5 /usr/lib64/samba/libmessages-dgm-samba4.so(+0x3341) [0x7fbb75857341]
Sep 21 19:34:38 fs03 smbd[4287]:   #6 /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7e25) [0x7fbb7a36de25]
Sep 21 19:34:38 fs03 smbd[4287]:   #7 /lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7fbb7657f34d]
Sep 21 19:34:38 fs03 smbd[4287]: [2017/09/21 19:34:38.624209,  0] ../source3/lib/dumpcore.c:315(dump_core)
Sep 21 19:34:38 fs03 smbd[4287]:  dumping core in /var/log/samba/cores/smbd
Sep 21 19:34:38 fs03 smbd[4287]: 
Sep 21 19:35:41 fs03 systemd-logind: New session 29 of user root.
Sep 21 19:35:41 fs03 systemd: Started Session 29 of user root.
Sep 21 19:35:41 fs03 systemd: Starting Session 29 of user root.
Sep 21 19:35:46 fs03 smbd[24327]: [2017/09/21 19:35:46.448052,  0] ../source3/lib/popt_common.c:67(popt_s3_talloc_log_fn)
Sep 21 19:35:46 fs03 smbd[24327]: [2017/09/21 19:35:46.448577,  0] ../source3/lib/util.c:791(smb_panic_s3)
Sep 21 19:35:46 fs03 smbd[24327]:  PANIC (pid 24327): Bad talloc magic value - wrong talloc version used/mixed
Sep 21 19:35:46 fs03 smbd[24327]: [2017/09/21 19:35:46.448961,  0] ../source3/lib/util.c:902(log_stack_trace)
Sep 21 19:35:46 fs03 smbd[24327]:  BACKTRACE: 8 stack frames:
Sep 21 19:35:46 fs03 smbd[24327]:   #0 /lib64/libsmbconf.so.0(log_stack_trace+0x1a) [0x7fbb77e336ba]
Sep 21 19:35:46 fs03 smbd[24327]:   #1 /lib64/libsmbconf.so.0(smb_panic_s3+0x20) [0x7fbb77e33790]
Sep 21 19:35:46 fs03 smbd[24327]:   #2 /lib64/libsamba-util.so.0(smb_panic+0x2f) [0x7fbb79f0e95f]
Sep 21 19:35:46 fs03 smbd[24327]:   #3 /lib64/libtalloc.so.2(_talloc_get_type_abort+0x102) [0x7fbb76c6b702]
Sep 21 19:35:46 fs03 smbd[24327]:   #4 /usr/lib64/samba/libmessages-dgm-samba4.so(+0x3c67) [0x7fbb75857c67]
Sep 21 19:35:46 fs03 smbd[24327]:   #5 /usr/lib64/samba/libmessages-dgm-samba4.so(+0x3341) [0x7fbb75857341]
Sep 21 19:35:46 fs03 smbd[24327]:   #6 /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7e25) [0x7fbb7a36de25]
Sep 21 19:35:46 fs03 smbd[24327]:   #7 /lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7fbb7657f34d]
Sep 21 19:35:46 fs03 smbd[24327]: [2017/09/21 19:35:46.449544,  0] ../source3/lib/dumpcore.c:315(dump_core)
Sep 21 19:35:46 fs03 smbd[24327]:  dumping core in /var/log/samba/cores/smbd
Sep 21 19:35:46 fs03 smbd[24327]: 
Sep 21 19:50:41 fs03 smbd[25068]: [2017/09/21 19:50:41.975028,  0] ../source3/lib/popt_common.c:67(popt_s3_talloc_log_fn)
Sep 21 19:50:41 fs03 smbd[25068]: [2017/09/21 19:50:41.975395,  0] ../source3/lib/util.c:791(smb_panic_s3)
Sep 21 19:50:41 fs03 smbd[25068]: [2017/09/21 19:50:41.975415,  0] ../source3/lib/popt_common.c:67(popt_s3_talloc_log_fn)
Sep 21 19:50:41 fs03 smbd[25068]:  PANIC (pid 25068): Bad talloc magic value - wrong talloc version used/mixed#012Bad talloc magic value - wrong talloc version used/mixed
Sep 21 19:50:41 fs03 smbd[25068]: [2017/09/21 19:50:41.975577,  0] ../source3/lib/util.c:791(smb_panic_s3)
Sep 21 19:50:41 fs03 smbd[25068]:  PANIC (pid 25068): Bad talloc magic value - wrong talloc version used/mixed
Sep 21 19:50:41 fs03 smbd[25068]: 
Sep 21 19:50:41 fs03 smbd[25068]: [2017/09/21 19:50:41.975974,  0] ../source3/lib/util.c:902(log_stack_trace)
Sep 21 19:50:41 fs03 smbd[25068]:  BACKTRACE: 8 stack frames:
Sep 21 19:50:41 fs03 smbd[25068]:   #0 /lib64/libsmbconf.so.0(log_stack_trace+0x1a) [0x7fbb77e336ba]
Sep 21 19:50:41 fs03 smbd[25068]:   #1 /lib64/libsmbconf.so.0(smb_panic_s3+0x20) [0x7fbb77e33790]
Sep 21 19:50:41 fs03 smbd[25068]:   #2 /lib64/libsamba-util.so.0(smb_panic+0x2f) [0x7fbb79f0e95f]
Sep 21 19:50:41 fs03 smbd[25068]:  BACKTRACE: 8 stlib64/libtalloc.so.2(_talloc_get_type_abort+0x102) [0x7fbb76c6b702]
Sep 21 19:50:41 fs03 smbd[25068]:   #4 /usr/lib64/samba/libmessages-dgm-samba4.so(+0x3c67) [0x7fbb75857c67]
Sep 21 19:50:41 fs03 smbd[25068]:   #0 /lib64/libsmbconf.so.0(log_stack_trace+0x1a) [0x7fbb77e336ba]
Sep 21 19:50:41 fs03 smbd[25068]:   #5 /usr/lib64/samba/libmessages-dgm-samba4.so(+0x3341) [0x7fbb75857341]
Sep 21 19:50:41 fs03 smbd[25068]:   #1 /lib64/libsmbconf.so.0(smb_panic_s3+0x20) [0x7fbb77e33790]
Sep 21 19:50:41 fs03 smbd[25068]:   #1 /lib64/libsmbconf.so.0(smb_panic_s3+0x20) [0x7fbb77e33790]
Sep 21 19:50:41 fs03 smbd[25068]: [2017/09/21 19:50:41.976485,  0] ../source3/lib/dumpcore.c:315(dump_core)
Sep 21 19:50:41 fs03 smbd[25068]:   #5 /usr/lib64/samba/libmessages-dgm-samba4.so(+0x3341) [0x7fbb75857341]
Sep 21 19:50:41 fs03 smbd[25068]:   #6 /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7e25) [0x7fbb7a36de25]
Sep 21 19:50:41 fs03 smbd[25068]: 
Sep 21 19:50:41 fs03 smbd[25068]:   #6 /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7e25) [0x7fbb7a36de25]
Sep 21 19:50:41 fs03 smbd[25068]:   #7 /lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7fbb7657f34d]
Sep 21 19:50:41 fs03 smbd[25068]: [2017/09/21 19:50:41.976862,  0] ../source3/lib/dumpcore.c:273(dump_core)
Sep 21 19:50:41 fs03 smbd[25068]:  dump_core() called recursive
Sep 21 19:57:18 fs03 smbd[27177]: [2017/09/21 19:57:18.950112,  0] ../lib/util/fault.c:78(fault_report)
Sep 21 19:57:18 fs03 smbd[27177]: [2017/09/21 19:57:18.951433,  0] ../lib/util/fault.c:81(fault_report)
Sep 21 19:57:18 fs03 smbd[27177]:  ===============================================================
Sep 21 19:57:18 fs03 smbd[27177]: [2017/09/21 19:57:18.970608,  0] ../source3/lib/util.c:902(log_stack_trace)
Sep 21 19:57:18 fs03 smbd[27177]:  BACKTRACE: 12 stack frames:
Sep 21 19:57:18 fs03 smbd[27177]:   #0 /lib64/libsmbconf.so.0(log_stack_trace+0x1a) [0x7fbb77e336ba]
Sep 21 19:57:18 fs03 smbd[27177]:  BACKTRACE: 12 stack frames:#012smb2_write failed: fnum 3359156866, file IT/tmp-files/10G (5), length=65536 offset=0 nwritten=-1: NT_STATUS_NETWORK_BUSY
Sep 21 19:57:18 fs03 smbd[27177]: 
Sep 21 19:57:18 fs03 smbd[27177]: [2017/09/21 19:57:18.972518,  0] ../source3/lib/dumpcore.c:315(dump_core)
Sep 21 19:57:18 fs03 smbd[27177]:  dumping core in /var/log/samba/cores/smbd
Sep 21 19:57:18 fs03 smbd[27177]: 
Sep 22 09:27:51 fs03 journal: out of memory [2273]
Sep 22 09:27:51 fs03 journal: out of memory [2273]
Sep 22 09:27:51 fs03 journal: out of memory [2273]
Sep 22 09:27:51 fs03 journal: out of memory [2273]
Sep 22 09:27:51 fs03 journal: out of memory [2273]
Sep 22 09:27:51 fs03 journal: out of memory [2273]
Sep 22 09:27:51 fs03 journal: out of memory [2273]
Sep 22 09:27:51 fs03 journal: out of memory [2273]
Sep 22 09:27:51 fs03 journal: out of memory [2273]
Sep 22 09:27:51 fs03 journal: out of memory [2273]
Sep 22 09:27:51 fs03 journal: out of memory [2273]
Sep 22 09:27:51 fs03 journal: out of memory [2273]
Sep 22 09:27:51 fs03 journal: out of memory [2273]
Sep 22 09:27:51 fs03 journal: out of memory [2273]
Sep 22 09:27:51 fs03 journal: out of memory [2273]
Sep 22 09:27:51 fs03 smbd[2273]: [2017/09/22 09:27:51.248367,  0] ../source3/lib/dumpcore.c:315(dump_core)
Sep 22 09:27:51 fs03 smbd[2273]:  dumping core in /var/log/samba/cores/smbd
Sep 22 09:27:51 fs03 smbd[2273]:
Sep 22 09:27:52 fs03 journal: out of memory [2275]
Sep 22 09:27:52 fs03 journal: out of memory [2275]
Sep 22 09:27:52 fs03 journal: out of memory [2275]
Sep 22 09:27:52 fs03 journal: out of memory [2275]
Sep 22 09:27:52 fs03 journal: out of memory [2275]
Sep 22 09:27:52 fs03 journal: out of memory [2275]
Sep 22 09:27:52 fs03 journal: out of memory [2275]
Sep 22 09:27:52 fs03 journal: out of memory [2275]
Sep 22 09:27:52 fs03 journal: out of memory [2275]
Sep 22 09:27:52 fs03 journal: out of memory [2275]
Sep 22 09:27:52 fs03 journal: out of memory [2275]
Sep 22 09:27:52 fs03 journal: out of memory [2275]
Sep 22 09:27:52 fs03 journal: out of memory [2275]
Sep 22 09:27:52 fs03 journal: out of memory [2275]
Sep 22 09:27:52 fs03 journal: out of memory [2275]
Sep 22 09:27:52 fs03 journal: out of memory [2275]
Sep 22 09:27:52 fs03 journal: out of memory [2275]
Sep 22 09:27:52 fs03 journal: out of memory [2275]
Sep 22 09:27:52 fs03 journal: out of memory [2275]
Sep 22 09:27:52 fs03 journal: out of memory [2275]
Sep 22 09:27:52 fs03 journal: out of memory [2275]
Sep 22 09:27:52 fs03 journal: out of memory [2275]
Sep 22 09:27:52 fs03 journal: out of memory [2275]
Sep 22 09:27:52 fs03 journal: out of memory [2275]
Sep 22 09:27:52 fs03 smbd[2275]: [2017/09/22 09:27:52.305728,  0] ../source3/lib/dumpcore.c:315(dump_core)
Sep 22 09:27:52 fs03 smbd[2275]:  dumping core in /var/log/samba/cores/smbd
Sep 22 09:27:52 fs03 smbd[2275]:
Sep 22 09:27:53 fs03 smbd[2280]: [2017/09/22 09:27:53.036463,  0] ../lib/util/charset/codepoints.c:16630(get_conv_handle)
Sep 22 09:27:53 fs03 smbd[2280]:  dos charset 'CP850' unavailable - using ASCII
Sep 22 09:28:12 fs03 journal: out of memory [2280]
Sep 22 09:28:12 fs03 journal: out of memory [2280]
Sep 22 09:28:12 fs03 journal: out of memory [2280]
Sep 22 09:28:12 fs03 journal: out of memory [2280]
Sep 22 09:28:12 fs03 journal: out of memory [2280]
Sep 22 09:28:12 fs03 journal: out of memory [2280]
Sep 22 09:28:12 fs03 journal: out of memory [2280]
Sep 22 09:28:12 fs03 journal: out of memory [2280]
Sep 22 09:28:12 fs03 journal: out of memory [2280]
Sep 22 09:28:12 fs03 journal: out of memory [2280]
Sep 22 09:28:12 fs03 journal: out of memory [2280]
Sep 22 09:28:12 fs03 journal: out of memory [2280]
Sep 22 09:28:12 fs03 journal: out of memory [2280]
Sep 22 09:28:12 fs03 journal: out of memory [2280]
Sep 22 09:28:12 fs03 journal: out of memory [2280]
Sep 22 09:28:12 fs03 journal: out of memory [2280]
Sep 22 09:28:12 fs03 journal: out of memory [2280]
Sep 22 09:28:12 fs03 journal: out of memory [2280]
Sep 22 09:28:12 fs03 journal: out of memory [2280]
Sep 22 09:28:12 fs03 journal: out of memory [2280]
Sep 22 09:28:12 fs03 journal: out of memory [2280]
Sep 22 09:28:12 fs03 journal: out of memory [2280]
Sep 22 09:28:12 fs03 journal: out of memory [2280]
Sep 22 09:28:12 fs03 journal: out of memory [2280]
Sep 22 09:28:12 fs03 smbd[2280]: [2017/09/22 09:28:12.927151,  0] ../source3/lib/dumpcore.c:315(dump_core)
Sep 22 09:28:12 fs03 smbd[2280]:  dumping core in /var/log/samba/cores/smbd
Sep 22 09:28:12 fs03 smbd[2280]:
```

Here is my smbd info:

```
[root@fs03 ~]# smbd -i
smbd version 4.6.2 started.
Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2017
Registered MSG_REQ_POOL_USAGE
Registered MSG_REQ_DMALLOC_MARK and LOG_CHANGED
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
Processing section "[data]"
Processing section "[data2]"
Processing section "[data3]"
Processing section "[data4]"
Processing section "[data5]"
Processing section "[data6]"
added interface eth0 ip=10.10.xxx.xx bcast=10.10.xxx.255 netmask=255.255.255.0
INFO: Profiling turned OFF from pid 15718
ERROR: smbd is already running. File /run/smbd.pid exists and process id 1623 is running.
[root@fs03 ~]#
```

Here is my samba log file:

```
[2017/09/22 11:05:34.330357,  0] ../source3/lib/popt_common.c:67(popt_s3_talloc_log_fn)
  Bad talloc magic value - wrong talloc version used/mixed
[2017/09/22 11:05:34.330438,  0] ../source3/lib/util.c:791(smb_panic_s3)
  PANIC (pid 23023): Bad talloc magic value - wrong talloc version used/mixed
[2017/09/22 11:05:34.330758,  0] ../source3/lib/util.c:902(log_stack_trace)
  BACKTRACE: 8 stack frames:
   #0 /lib64/libsmbconf.so.0(log_stack_trace+0x1a) [0x7fd1088416ba]
   #1 /lib64/libsmbconf.so.0(smb_panic_s3+0x20) [0x7fd108841790]
   #2 /lib64/libsamba-util.so.0(smb_panic+0x2f) [0x7fd10a91c95f]
   #3 /lib64/libtalloc.so.2(_talloc_get_type_abort+0x102) [0x7fd107679702]
   #4 /usr/lib64/samba/libmessages-dgm-samba4.so(+0x3c67) [0x7fd106265c67]
   #5 /usr/lib64/samba/libmessages-dgm-samba4.so(+0x3341) [0x7fd106265341]
   #6 /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7e25) [0x7fd10ad7be25]
   #7 /lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7fd106f8d34d]
[2017/09/22 11:05:34.330915,  0] ../source3/lib/dumpcore.c:315(dump_core)
  dumping core in /var/log/samba/cores/smbd
[2017/09/22 11:05:44.061157,  0] ../source3/lib/popt_common.c:67(popt_s3_talloc_log_fn)
  Bad talloc magic value - wrong talloc version used/mixed
[2017/09/22 11:05:44.061224,  0] ../source3/lib/util.c:791(smb_panic_s3)
  PANIC (pid 23229): Bad talloc magic value - wrong talloc version used/mixed
[2017/09/22 11:05:44.061545,  0] ../source3/lib/util.c:902(log_stack_trace)
  BACKTRACE: 8 stack frames:
   #0 /lib64/libsmbconf.so.0(log_stack_trace+0x1a) [0x7fd1088416ba]
   #1 /lib64/libsmbconf.so.0(smb_panic_s3+0x20) [0x7fd108841790]
   #2 /lib64/libsamba-util.so.0(smb_panic+0x2f) [0x7fd10a91c95f]
   #3 /lib64/libtalloc.so.2(_talloc_get_type_abort+0x102) [0x7fd107679702]
   #4 /usr/lib64/samba/libmessages-dgm-samba4.so(+0x3c67) [0x7fd106265c67]
   #5 /usr/lib64/samba/libmessages-dgm-samba4.so(+0x3341) [0x7fd106265341]
   #6 /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7e25) [0x7fd10ad7be25]
   #7 /lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7fd106f8d34d]
[2017/09/22 11:05:44.061655,  0] ../source3/lib/dumpcore.c:315(dump_core)
  dumping core in /var/log/samba/cores/smbd
```

Comment: Have you tried updating samba yet? 4.7 is out now.

Comment: Samba isn't working for Windows PCs, it is asking for password for the Samba account and isn't accepting it. However, it works for the Mac just fine.

Comment: @NathanC Is there a CentOS rep for Samba 4.7? Would updating to it cause any conflicts with CentOS 7.4?

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here:
[Windows PCs being asked for password after CentOS 7.4/Samba 4.6.2 upgrade?](https://serverfault.com/questions/875250/windows-pcs-being-asked-for-password-after-centos-7-4-samba-4-6-2-upgrade)

The solution was to add to the smb.conf in the Global section:

```
ntlm auth = yes
```

This might relate to your problem. There is an issue with NTLMv1 vs. NTLMv2, which is mentioned in the Samba 4.6.2 release notes.